# MIPS: Reading and displaying a character using polling

Tags: assembly, keyboard, mips, mars-simulator, memory-mapped-io

I am trying to display a single character in Mars MIPS (then eventually an entire string, but I am working on a single character for now).

```
.data

.text
main:
    jal emitchar
    jal LOOP
    jal LOOP2

emitchar:
    lui $t0, 0xFFFF         # $t0 stores the address of the receiver control

    jr $ra

LOOP:
    lw $t1, 0($t0)          # $t1 stores the entire 32-bits of the receiver control
    andi $t2, $t1, 0x0001       # $t2 stores the last bit (ready-bit) of the control
    beq $t2, $zero, LOOP        # if the ready-bit is 0 (not ready) loop until it is
    lw $s0, 4($t0)          # load the data into $v0

    jr $ra

LOOP2:
    lw $t1, 8($t0)          # $t1 is the address of transmitter control
    andi $t2, $t1, 0x0001       # $t2 is the ready-but of the transmitter control
    beq $t2, $zero, LOOP2       # if the ready-bit is 0 (not ready) loop until it is
    sw $s0, 12($t0)

    jr $ra
```

When debugging, I noticed that I am stuck in an infinite loop in the LOOP procedure. Any pointers on where to go from here?

Comment: Unable to reproduce. Make sure that Mapped IO is enabled in the settings of the simulator you're using, then enter a character into the simulator's console window while your program is running. And of course you need to do something after `jal LOOP2` returns, e.g. terminating the program with system call 10.

Comment: After entering a character in the MMIO simulator, the ready bit of the control turns on and the code executes to LOOP2. However, the code reaches the instruction sw $s0, 12($t0), but nothing is printed to the screen. I also added a syscall 10 in my main like you suggested. @Michael

Comment: The character you enter at the console will be echoed to the console. If you want it to be displayed more than once you need to write it more than once.

Comment: I'm not understanding. How do I display the character to the screen? @Michael

Comment: You already are. Try removing the `sw` and you'll see that the program finishes without echoing the character you input to the console. If you want the character to be shown more than once you have to do the write procedure more than once.

Comment: In the MARS simulator there is a MMIO simulator that is contains separate keyboard and display segments. In the display part (stores to transmitter data 0xffff000c), nothing is appearing when I manually enter a character in the keyboard part. @Michael

Comment: Uncheck the "DAD" option and press "Connect to MIPS" on the MMIO simulator window. Or switch to PCSpim or QtSpim.